# Is an accidentally omnipotent being **more powerful** than essentially omnipotent being?

Tags: theology, omnipotence

An **accidentally omnipotent being** (AOB) is an entity that can be omnipotent for a temporary period of time, and then becomes non-omnipotent. That is it can do anything that is logically possible.

An **essentially omnipotent being** (EOB) is an entity that is necessarily omnipotent. That is it can do anything that is logically possible as long as it does not lose its omnipotence.

Consider the question "Can an omnipotent being create a stone which is so hard that even the omnipotent being cannot break it?"

An AOB can make such a stone but it will lose its omnipotence in the process. But an EOB can not make such a stone because the EOB cannot do anything which makes it lose its omnipotence.

Note that we are only talking about "can" (the capability) not whether they will do it.

**Anything an EOB can do can also be done by an AOB because the things EOB can do are a subset of things AOB can do.** In principle an AOB can avoid doing anything which makes it lose its omnipotence and become like an EOB.

If ever an omnipotent being gets bored of omnipotence AOB can lose it but EOB can not lose it. An AOB can kill itself (and lose omnipotence in that process) but an EOB can not do such a task. **In this sense isn't AOB more powerful than EOB?**

Comment: Since AOB can do anything in its time it can make itself OB permanently, so there is no difference in what they can do. For that matter, either of them can exit time altogether. Even aside from that, your stone is equivocally described. AOB can create a stone *AOB* cannot lift, EOB cannot create a stone *EOB* cannot lift, those are two different stones. And "anything logically possible" is vacuous to begin with. Possibility is not additive, individually possible items may not be possible collectively. So possibility cannot be used to select items and form the supposed "anything" out of them.

Comment: @Conifold "those are two different stones" why, can you elaborate? Both stones have the same property (i.e. they are unbreakable).

Comment: can an AOB create a stone too heavy for an EOB to lift?

Comment: @Ewan that question doesn't make sense. If the stone mass is more than earths mass then you will indirectly lift Earth with your legs from falling.

Comment: The main principle here is that the omnipotent being cannot be asked to do something contradictory or contrary. With that being said it is impossible for more than one omnipotent being to exist. If we had being K & being L that were both omnipotent allegedly then the proposition K would be able to make L jump must be true or K is not omnipotent. If K cannot make being L jump we know K is not omnipotent. Now we reverse the question to being L. Either he can make being K jump or not. If L does make K jump on command anytime we now say L is indeed the omnipotent one. It could be there is none.

Comment: The stones are described not by a property "unbreakable", but by a relation "unbreakable-by", with two *different* (at least in your intention) means implied after "by". Unbreakable-by hand and unbreakable-by axe will similarly describe different objects. You then attempt to compare your beings on *their* relation to apples and oranges, effectively, by using an abridged description that hides the difference. Look also at Russell's paradox: the set of all sets not containing themselves is incoherent, the set of all subsets of a *given* set not containing themselves is a perfectly fine set.

Comment: Your question implies that the beings you're calling "omnipotent" are bound by physics (e.g., time and molecular properties that determine properties like "hardness"). Is that intentional?

Comment: @StevenHarder I never assumed that they are bound by physics. AOB creating a stone that is unbreakable is a violation of physical laws. But I assumed that they are bound by logic.

Comment: Sure you did some of it. Your beings exist in time, apparently, and "unbreakable" requires some physics of matter composition to even be defined.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we could differentiate between qualitative omnipotence and quantitative omnipotence. There are, perhaps,* qualitatively more natural numbers in the set of both odd and even numbers, than in the sets of either only odd or even numbers, but quantitatively, any of these sets is the same in size as the others. So by comparison, the AOB has the same quantity of power as the EOB (an absolutely infinite amount, perhaps, no less!), while having a slightly "greater degree" of qualitative power (think then of the difference between, for example, ω and ω + ω: both have the same cardinality, though the latter is ordinally "taller").

*<sub>But perhaps not: there might be as many subdescriptions, among either just the odd or even numbers, as there are subdescriptions among both all the odd and even numbers. For example, besides 2, the set of even numbers encodes no primes, so the description "contains almost all primes" applies to the set of odd numbers. I'm not smart enough about all this to decide this question even for my own sake.</sub>